# XNA Drawing a series of squares

Tags: xna

I am trying to draw a series of squares in XNA. I am looking at all these articles about TriangleStrips and DynamicVertexBuffers. But, not sure where to begin.

**Current step**
I am able to draw 1 square using VertexPositionColor, TriangleList and indices. Now I want to draw a series of squares with varying colors.

**End Goal**
Something to keep in mind is the number of such squares that I would like to be able to draw, eventually. If we assume a 5px width, on a 1920x1080 screen, we can calculate the number of squares to be (1920 * 1080) / 25 = 82944.

Any pointers on how to accomplish this would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you can draw more squares in the same way you draw the first one. However, there will be a significant loss in performance.

Instead, you can add all triangles to one vertex buffer / index buffer. You already are able to draw two triangles as a triangle list. You should be able to easily adjust this routine to draw more than two triangles. Just add the according vertices and indices to the buffers and modify the draw call.

If you need vertices at the same position with different colors, you need to add two vertices to the buffer.

This way, the performance loss is very little, because you draw everything with only one draw call. Although the amount of triangles should be no problem for most graphic cards, some smaller or older ones can get into trouble. If so, you should consider changing your drawing strategy. Maybe it is not even necessary to draw that much triangles. But you can think about that, if the resulting performance is too low...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about 3D, just 2D - you can use [SpriteBatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.aspx) to draw squares/rectangles on the screen. This will handle batching all the vertex/index buffer management for you.

Comment: Fair enough. Leaving this answer here in case someone else who does not care about 3D lands here.